# BeautifulSoup - Getting class from elements of findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a website using BeautifulSoup. I know that the content I want is in a `div` of class `content`. And that the content is all in `p` tags. So I ran

```
paragraphs= content.findAll('p')
```

It is fine till here. I iterate over the list, and have an `if` condition that'll break out of the loop if a particular class is encountered.

```
for para in paragraphs:
    if 'class' in para:
        if para['class']=='end':
            break
```

But this isn't working. When I run the loop it doesn't break when the `end` class is encountered. In fact, while iterating over the loop, the classes of all the elements seem to get lost.

```
for para in paragraphs:
    if 'class' in para:
        print para['class']
```

This prints out nothing, even though there are elements with classes. In fact, this piece of code does print out the class -

```
>>>paragraphs[0]['class']
u'dateline'
```

But,

```
>>> print 'class' in paragraphs[0]
False
```

I don't quiet understand what is going on here. Eventually I solved my problem by using exceptions, but this is kinda bugging me. Can anybody explain what is happening here?

Comment: Which website are you parsing?

Comment: @Haidro Aaron Schwartzs blog. But I [did](https://github.com/elssar/aaronsw_RawThought) what I wanted to do, it's just that this thing confused me a bit and I was wondering what was going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you're putting `if 'class' in para`, you're literally saying if there was the *actual* word class in the paragraph. I believe your intention was to see if it has a class, so what you want is:

```
for para in paragraphs:
    if para.has_attr('class'):
        if para['class'][0] == 'end': # Notice that I put [0], as para['class'] is a list.
            break
```

Comment: UserWarning: has_key is deprecated. Use has_attr("class") instead.